# Why is discord.py not functioning properly? (SETUP)

Tags: discord, discord.py

```
import requests
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
```

On line 3 where I do import commands, it says 'Unresolved Reference Commands'

I am really confused and would appreciate some help :)

Thanks

Comment: What version of Discord.py are you using? (`pip show discord.py` in console to see)

Comment: It's fixed now, thanks anyway!